# Check login user exists in sharepoint site?

Tags: user

We are creating mobile app for SharePoint 2010 site.when mobile user enter user name and password .How i check that user exsists in AD or not .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, following should help:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

PS: It has nothing to do with SharePoint, but you can use it in SharePoint.. You might need to put the code in RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: Thnx a lot Arsalan.

Comment: @Jon if the above answer was helpful, please mark it correct with a Green tick available with the answer to close the Question..